# Passing Serializable Class To Parent Activity with Support Action Bar

Tags: android

I am attempting to pass an instance of a serializable class to a parent activity when the user clicks on the up navigation button in the support action bar. The activity in which I am having trouble was started with startActivityForResult() so I can successfuly pass the instance through an intent with the onBackPressed() method overwritten like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("world_key", world);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

but I am lost when attempting to run the same code when the user clicks on the up navigation on the support action bar in my activity

for extra clarity on what I am trying at the moment, I have tried the following, which has not worked

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.toolbar:
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("world_key", world);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `android.R.id.home` like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      // send bundle here.
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```